# SMTP send mail cancelled

Tags: c#, email, smtp, async-await

Try to send a mail, but the task is cancelled. Any idea why?

```
public static Task SendAsync(this SmtpClient client, MailMessage message)
{
    TaskCompletionSource<object> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
    Guid sendGuid = Guid.NewGuid();

    SendCompletedEventHandler handler = null;
    handler = (o, ea) =>
    {
        if (ea.UserState is Guid && ((Guid)ea.UserState) == sendGuid)
        {
            client.SendCompleted -= handler;
            if (ea.Cancelled)
            {
                tcs.SetCanceled(); // TASK CANCELLED: Why?
            }
            else if (ea.Error != null)
            {
                tcs.SetException(ea.Error);
            }
            else
            {
                tcs.SetResult(null);
            }
        }
    };

    client.SendCompleted += handler;
    client.SendAsync(message, sendGuid);
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Called by:

```
using( SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient() )
{
    return smtpClient.SendAsync(msg);
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!
Gerard

Comment: Have you tried debugging the code?

Comment: Yes, but no clue yet. It worked fine for some mails, but since today mails are cancelled.

Comment: Looks the problem is caused by the Using-statement. Looks the smtp-client is out of scope before completing the task, which seems to cancel the task. Without the Using-statement the code runs fine.

Comment: Hah, i just posted an answer a couple of minutes ago :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `using` statement will call an objects `Dispose` method when finishing the execution block. Calling `smtpClient.SendAsync` without using `await` on the async method will cause the execution block to end and `Dispose` will be called on `SmtpClient`, even though the `SendAsync` method is still executing, which explains why *some* mails finish as some may complete before disposing the objects and others dont.

Do this:

```
using (SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient())
{
    await smtpClient.SendAsync(msg);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, found that too (see comment above). What if you don't want to wait? Will SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient(); followed by smtpClient.SendAsync(msg); work? It seems to work or is it just luck (smtpClient not disposed yet).

Comment: It's just luck, you cant rely on it finishing before the using statement ends. You can dispose sntp manually yourself without `using`

Comment: I think you mean `SendMailAsync` not `SendAsync`.

Comment: @ChrisW No, OP created an extension method called `SendAsync`, that's the one I'm referring to.